# In JavaScript, what is the default value of a function's prototype property?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, prototype

In Chrome's JavaScript console:

```
function placeOrder() {
        return 1;
};
undefined
console.log(placeOrder.prototype);
placeOrder {}
```

But In IE 11, the default prototype property seems to be an empty object.
I wonder what is the object "placeOrder { }" in Chrome? 
I also tested it in Firefox. In Firefox, the prototype property is "placeOrder { }" too.

In IE 11 console:

```
function placeOrder() {
        return 1;
};
undefined
console.log(placeOrder.prototype);
undefined
[object Object]{}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an object which inherits from `Object.prototype` and has an own `constructor` property whose value is the constructor function.

See [Creating Function Objects](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2)

> 16. Let *proto* be the result of creating a new object as would be constructed by the expression `new Object()` where `Object` is the
>       standard built-in constructor with that name.
> 17. Call the [[DefineOwnProperty]] internal method of *proto* with arguments `"constructor"`, [Property Descriptor](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.10) {[[Value]]: *F*, {
>       [[Writable]]: **true**, [[Enumerable]]: **false**, [[Configurable]]:
>       **true**}, and **false**.
> 18. Call the [[DefineOwnProperty]] internal method of *F* with arguments `"prototype"`, [Property Descriptor](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.10) {[[Value]]: *proto*,
>       { [[Writable]]: **true**, [[Enumerable]]: **false**, [[Configurable]]:
>       **false**}, and **false**.

Comment: @thermostat That would be a violation of the spec. Probably, it's not an empty object, but IE displays it as an empty object in the console because it has no enumerable property. Use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(placeOrder.prototype)` and you will see its own properties.

Comment: on ie11 it returns constructor